# trying to find code to force users not to leave cells unpopulated

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks Guys. I used the following code to get an error message to pop up if I attempt to save the sheet with one or more of the specified cells left blank. However, when I then go back and populate all the specified blank cells, and then save, I still get the error message. where am I going wrong?

```
Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim Cell As Range
Dim flag As Boolean
flag = False
If Cells(1, 1) = "" Then flag = True
For Each Cell In Range("C9:C14")
If Cell = "" Then
flag = True
Exit For
End If
Next Cell
For Each Cell In Range("C18:C25")
If Cell = "" Then
flag = True
Exit For
End If
Next Cell
For Each Cell In Range("C30:E35")
If Cell = "" Then
flag = True
  Exit For
End If
Next Cell
Cancel = flag
If flag Then MsgBox "error message"
End Sub
```

Comment: to give you a start ... first you need to decide on strategy: should A) the user always have a display of current status (incomplete / complete+wrong sum / complete+correct) or B) should this info be shown upon leaving this sheet or C) should info be shown on closing sheet (with or without saving) ... from this it depends which event triggers you choose to implement that check

Comment: A simple way, `A2=IF(COUNT(A3:A7)<>5,"Incomplete",SUM(A3:A7))`

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 small functions checking if "a range" contains any empty cells and if sum of "one range" is equal to sum of "another range". I say this a bit abstract because your ranges may be larger tomorrow or in a different position and you may not want to recode your app time & again.

```
Function IsFilled(TestRange As Range) As Boolean
Dim C As Range

    IsFilled = True
    For Each C In TestRange.Cells
        If C = "" Then
            IsFilled = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next C
End Function

Function IsSum(TestRange As Range, TestSum As Range) As Boolean

    IsSum = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(TestRange) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(TestSum))

End Function
```

In your context, both functions must evaluate to `True` for user entry to be valid.

Now you can

- enter these functions into two cells of your worksheet (e.g. `=isfilled(A2:A7)`, `=issum(A3:A7;A2)`) and tell users they have to work hard to make both `True`
- evaluate the two results from above in any appropriate event `Sub()`, e.g. in a `Worksheet_Deactivate()`, `Workbook_BeforeSave()` (I prefer BeforeSave over BeforeClose as the user may want to escape w/o saving in which case I wouldn't need to validate)
- directly call and evaluate these two functions from an appropriate event without using them in the worksheet
- in any case the validating `Sub()` must terminate its default action and display a `MsgBox()` in case validation fails.